# Can't rendering JSON to HTML by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I want to ask about JSON,
here is the JSON

```
{
 "city":[
          {
           "city":"Jakarta",
           "count":"747"
          },

          {
            "city":"Bali",
            "count":"600"
          }
        ]
}
```

And my JavaScript

```
var $content = $(".wrapper");
$.ajax({
   url         : "http://myapi.com",
   type        : "GET",
   dataType    : "json",
   success     : function(data){
       $.each(data, function(i, data){
       $content.append("<div class='city'>"+ data.city +"</div><div class='jumlah'>"+ data.count +"</div>");});
      },
error:function(){
      alert('error');
   }
});
```

My HTML Page

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="city"></div>
   <div class="jumlah"></div>
</div>
```

I want to show '**city** and **count**' but the result is '**undefined undefined**'. Anybody can help me? Thank you

Comment: Yes I understand, it works! Thank's a lot nnnnnn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
   $.each(data, function(i, data){
```

to this:

```
   $.each(data.city, function(i, data){
```

The `data` variable that is the argument of your `success` function refers to the whole object, but what you actually seem to want to iterate over is that object's `city` property, which is an array of objects.